# Async Transactions in MVC .NET 4.7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, transactions

Using Microsoft MVC .NET 4.7.2.

My question relates to using a SqlTransaction in an Async method as below.

```
public async Task DeleteSomethingAsync(int id)
{
    SqlTransaction sqlTransaction = null;

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();

                using (sqlTransaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
                {
                    sqlCommand.Transaction = sqlTransaction;

                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = id });

                    sqlCommand.CommandText = @"DELETE FROM first_table "
                                           + @"WHERE (some_id = @Id)";

                    await sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                    sqlCommand.CommandText = @"DELETE FROM second_table "
                                           + @"WHERE (some_id = @Id) ";

                    await sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                    sqlTransaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Some error logging blah.

        try
        {
            sqlTransaction?.Rollback();
        }
        catch
        {
            // Some error logging blah.
        }
    }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any type of sqlConnection.BeginTransaction**Async**.

There does seem to be a method BeginTransactionAsync for .NET Core.

There also from some MS Docs seems to be this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/asynchronous-programming

```
// Start a local transaction.  
transaction = await Task.Run<SqlTransaction>(  
    () => connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction")  
);
```

That doesn't seem appropriate within IIS (maybe I'm wrong?)

As it seems to be the case with most things Microsoft now the information is all over the place.

What is the correct way to use a transaction in an Async method in 2018+ using MVC and .NET 4.7.2.

Comment: The `BeginTransaction` method is not asynchronous. It simply creates an instance of a `SqlTransaction` object.

Comment: I know it isnt, that is sort of the whole point of the question which that response doesnt answer.

Comment: So why do you expect it to be implemented as an asynchronous method when it simply creates an object in memory...? This makes no sense at all.

Comment: Again thats what Im asking. And if thats the case why are Microsoft creating async versions for .NET Core and giving instructions to put it in another Task. Personally I would of thought its ok for the reasons you describe but all the extra docs is whats throwing me.

Comment: I don't know which method you are referring to. `SqlConnection.BeginTransaction` is not async in .NET Core.

Comment: As Ive said in the question .NET Core has the BeginTransactionAsync Method. If it isnt required whats it there for?

Comment: Again, what class in .NET Core are you referring to? Obviously this class has another implementation than the `SqlConnection` class. Whether the method is async depends on the implementation.

Comment: (Though it may just be an EF thing?)

Comment: How is EF related to your question about .NET Core. They have their own methods...

Comment: Its not. I only say that as Im reading though docs on the MS site. And it appears that SqlConnection.BeginTransactionAsync is a EF thing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.internal.sqlserverconnection.

Comment: Yes, clearly. This is not a .NET API. So what is your actual question?

Comment: "What is the correct way to use a transaction in an Async method in 2018+ using MVC and .NET 4.7.2.". If it is how Ive done it then fine, but if that is the case why are the MS docs doing it differently.

Comment: Your current implementation seems fine to me. There is no reason to call the BeginTransaction method on a background thread in an ASP.NET controller.

Comment: If there is no async version then you are best off calling the sync version. using Task.Run only creates overhead. It does not create true async IO and it does not achieve the usual goal of async which is to free threads. Also, most web apps are not constrained by threads so all this async database IO likely gains you exactly zero throughput.

Comment: The actual real code is far far more complicated than the example but you have both answered what I thought myself. Thank you for clarifying.